# How to fix EF Core database errors after extending IdentityUser in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core-3.1

I've built a web app in ASP.NET Core 3.1, using Entity Framework Core 3.1 as well, and am now trying to Publish it to Azure. However, at the point in development when I extended the built-in IdentityUser class with a custom ApplicationUser class, my EF migrations stopped posting to the database. The migrations successfully were created, but the update-database command always failed.

Because I couldn't understand the error messages, I simply manually updated the database tables based on the information contained in each of my subsequent migrations files. This worked fine while still developing, but now that I want to publish the app to Azure, the same errors are preventing the app from being able to host on Azure at all.

Basically, when Azure tries to create the database, the exact same errors that I ran into during development prevent the successful creation of the database. And because I used a manual workaround during development, I have no idea how to solve the errors now when trying to publish the app to Azure.

Below is the error message I get when trying to publish to Azure:

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.b__3()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__213.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

===================

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Web deployment task failed. (An error occurred during execution of the database script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script: "568" and "581". The verbose log might have more information about the error. The command started with the following:
"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHisto"
 The object 'PK_AspNetUserTokens' is dependent on column 'Name'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Name failed because one or more objects access this column. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.)
Failed to publish the database. This can happen if the remote database cannot run the script. Try modifying the database scripts, or disabling database publishing in the Package/Publish Web properties page. If the script failed due to database tables already exist, try dropping existing database objects before creating new ones. For more information on doing these options from Visual Studio, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179181.
Error details:
An error occurred during execution of the database script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script: "568" and "581". The verbose log might have more information about the error. The command started with the following:
"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHisto"
 The object 'PK_AspNetUserTokens' is dependent on column 'Name'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Name failed because one or more objects access this column. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.
The object 'PK_AspNetUserTokens' is dependent on column 'Name'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Name failed because one or more objects access this column.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DBStatementInfo.Execute(DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, Int32 timeout)    BethanysPieShop     0

Below is the related error I get any time I run the update-database command in the Package Manager Console during development:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (1,684ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='120']
      DECLARE @var2 sysname;
      SELECT @var2 = [d].[name]
      FROM [sys].[default_constraints] [d]
      INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] [c] ON [d].[parent_column_id] = [c].[column_id] AND [d].[parent_object_id] = [c].[object_id]
      WHERE ([d].[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[AspNetUserTokens]') AND [c].[name] = N'Name');
      IF @var2 IS NOT NULL EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [AspNetUserTokens] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var2 + '];');
      ALTER TABLE [AspNetUserTokens] ALTER COLUMN [Name] nvarchar(128) NOT NULL;
Failed executing DbCommand (1,684ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='120']
DECLARE @var2 sysname;
SELECT @var2 = [d].[name]
FROM [sys].[default_constraints] [d]
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] [c] ON [d].[parent_column_id] = [c].[column_id] AND [d].[parent_object_id] = [c].[object_id]
WHERE ([d].[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[AspNetUserTokens]') AND [c].[name] = N'Name');
IF @var2 IS NOT NULL EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [AspNetUserTokens] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var2 + '];');
ALTER TABLE [AspNetUserTokens] ALTER COLUMN [Name] nvarchar(128) NOT NULL;
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The object 'PK_AspNetUserTokens' is dependent on column 'Name'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Name failed because one or more objects access this column.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:a2c8216d-8ba5-413c-8ab8-1526fdb7a7e7
Error Number:5074,State:1,Class:16
The object 'PK_AspNetUserTokens' is dependent on column 'Name'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Name failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

Comment: You've created a scenario where there's one or more keys depending on this column you're trying to alter. I'm not sure how you've managed to do that, but you'll need to remove the constraints before you can alter the column.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea how this happened either. When I review the code files, I can't see where the code got messed up. It has something to do with how the migrations are being compiled, but I can't understand them enough to see what the problem is. As far as I can tell, it has something to do with the typing of the columns being changed (no idea why the migrations do this), and the fact that the columns are referenced by other tables is throwing the exception.

Comment: Maybe you should show the code of this `ApplicationUser` and any mapping instructions you added in this area. As far as EF is concerned you changed the width of `ApplicationUser.Name` which is a PK field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best thing you could do in this case, since you don't have any real data to work with yet, is to remove your migrations if you have everything set at where you want it, wipe your database clean, and start your migrations and database from scratch.

I know this isn't the ideal way to handle it, but I think with you starting out with migrations and update-database, and then moving to manually updating the database with the migrations scripts, it's going to be hard and almost impossible to get it back to where you need it.

With a new migration, all of your tables should set correctly without error.

Source: I did the exact same thing as you did, now I'm very careful how I deal with migrations and make sure to apply them properly, and I have no more issues.

If you are using migrations and update-database, stick with that, I wouldn't manually do it with the scripts

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea, so I'm here to update based on the results:

I pushed the most recent complete working version of the app to GitHub as a new branch, downloaded the files, deleted the Migrations folder, dropped the old database from the original solution, changed the database name in the appsettings.json file of this newly downloaded version from GitHub, and then ran an InitialMigration using the Package Manager Console.

The migration completed successfully, but then when I ran update-database, I got this error:

Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E

Comment: Interesting. I did a quick search on that error and found that there are some memory issues with Unix/Linux

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13027

Comment: Yeah, I ended up finding that exact thing right after I posted the comment. I had too little RAM available at the moment I ran the command and just had to close a few things and try again. I currently am running into a different error, but before I post it I'll look it up and see if there's already a solution for it.

Comment: Definitely standing by, let me know if you get it.

Comment: I would post the full error output, but I'm not sure how to add a new post like I did originally. For now, I'll describe what happened. I did exactly what you suggested and everything worked great. New Migrations folder was created with one giant InitialMigration, and update-database worked perfectly and created a new database. Then when I went to publish to Azure, I got an error message saying that web deployment failed because there is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.

Comment: It might have already started part of the migration when you tried updating the azure database the first time. Do you have live data in it already? If not, you should wipe that database as well and set it from scratch. You can also back it up or name the old one something else if you need to.

Comment: You can also try select * from __EFMigrationsHistory to see if and what migrations have been applied.

Comment: As an update, the last error I mentioned was a problem with an existing Azure database, and not the actual codebase of the project after dropping the database in Visual Studio as you recommended. Everything is all fixed and working now, and your original solution of dropping the database and deleting the migrations was correct. Thanks for the help!